# PrimeFaces wizard not working with glassfish

Tags: primefaces

I have tried to implement [Primefaces wizard](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/wizard.jsf). The given example is correctly working in apache tomcat server. But not working in glassfish server.

Comment: do you see any errors in the server logs? what is the scope of your bean.. give all the relevant info...

Comment: No error in server log. Bean is in @ViewScoped. 
I have tried by adding atmosphere-runtime on glassfish lib, but still not working.

Comment: And if you change it into session scope ?

Comment: no change. I'm getting this warning on glassfish start-up : Unable to set request character encoding to UTF-8 from context , because request parameters have already been read, or ServletRequest.getReader() has already been called. Is it making problem. I have added `<parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8"/>` in sun-web.xml but still showing this warning.

Comment: do you have the jsf and primefaces jar on glassfish ? does a simple hello world works?

Comment: Yes, I've put all the required jars in glassfish/lib folder. And simple hello world program is working fine.